# mysql connection fails

Tags: php, sql, linux

I am using this code for mysql connection

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username" , "password");
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ');
    }
    else 
     { echo "connection failed....";}
   mysql_select_db("ManagersDatabase", $con);
```

mysql database are to be found in `/var/lib/mysql/ManagersDatabase`.
and my php pages are to be found in `/var/www/html/`.
It dosen't print anything. What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: You should never post your actual username and password in a question.

Comment: it is not my actual username and password....!!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: The original question looked like it could be, so I edited them out. If you already changed them prior to posting, all good :)

Comment: Does it not print _anything_ or does it print 'connection faile'?

Comment: check "Privileges" in your phpmyadmin or in your mysql database .The only problem can be the wrong username and password i thing if it is always outputting "Could Not Connect"

Comment: @Timm i am using printing just to know if the connection happend or not...

Comment: If "It dosen't print anything" means that blank page is outputted, there are two common reasons why. First, script exits (using `exit` or `die`) before interpreter reaches these lines. Second, You have some error in your script and error reporting is set to 0.

Comment: it give that: call to undefined function mysql_connect...how can i fix it? –

Answer (score 3):

This is how you should be connecting, by using PDO: [and utilizing prepared query's when querying.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
<?php 
try{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=your_database','root','password');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to database. Details:'.$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Or mysqli [and utilizing prepared query's when querying](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "your_database");
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$con->connect_errno.") ".$con->connect_error);
}
print_r($con);
?>
```

**Edit (Reply to comment):**
If you add `print_r($con);` you should see the mysqli connection object like:

```
/*
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $
    [client_version] => 50010
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.5.25a
    [server_version] => 50525
    [stat] => Uptime: 10  Threads: 1  Questions: 1  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 33  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.100
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 1
    [warning_count] => 0
)
*/
```

Other methods are outdated and soon tobe (thankfully) deprecated.

Comment: i tried mysqli way....but it didn't show any thing...is that mean the connection had done!!!

Comment: Yeah if no output happened that means it missed the `die('error')` and passed/connected.

Comment: switch from mysql_ to mysqli_ or PDO is just using another layer of abstraction. While I fully agree that the switch should be done, it doesn't really answer the question being asked here.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone,where can i add print_r?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone well, to begin with, using mysql_ is not inherently wrong. It was the recommended way for quite a while, and not all of us can upgrade their PHP stack. This is also speculation but if the user is seeing an empty page, switching an abstraction layer does not help, so it is "teaching something thats wrong" anyway - my guess is that the extension needs to be enabled and errors displayed...

Comment: it give that: call to undefined function mysql_connect...how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you should connect to your database in else block;

```
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username" , "password");
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ');
    }
    else    // if connection is made, then select the DB
     { 
       mysql_select_db("ManagersDatabase", $con);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from your question:

```
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ');
}
else 
 { echo "connection failed....";}
```

... you do notice it doesn't make much sense? it is saying if (something) { //could not connect } else { //connection failed } so your code thinks it is always failing.

What you should have is something like

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username" , "password");
if ($con === false)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ManagersDatabase", $con);
```

So it would actually print out anything.

Also, you should have either display_errors enabled to get the errors on screen or error_log in use so you would get the errors logged to somewhere.

In addition, please check you actually have the mysql extension enabled and in use, and mysql_connect() function available. phpinfo(); will tell what extensions you have, and function_exists() can tell you have the function available.

So, things to do:

1. Fix your code logic like listed above
2. Enable error printing or logging
3. Check that you have the mysql extension enabled
4. Check that mysql_connect() function actually is callable

---

**Edit**. as the missing mysql extension seems to be the problem ('call to undefined function mysql_connect'):

First of all, you need to have access to your PHP configuration. If this is your local installation or server, you should have that - if you are using someone elses hosting, they are the people who should change these things.

Given some assumptions, such as

- you are using your local apache server
- you are not using XAMPP or any other *AMP products, but vanilla installations

this is what you should do:

- Find your php.ini configuration file or create one based on example files in the PHP folder if you don't have one
- Find the lines below (.dll for windows, .so for linux, don't know about others)

---

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

---

- Strip out the comment (the first ';') from the one you want to use. You are using the first one in your example, the others are for using other abstractions described in some of the other postings here, so if you want to go with the code you have, you'd uncomment the first one.
- Enable "display_startup_errors" also if you want to see any configuration problems immediately
- Check that "extension_dir" setting is correct, and is pointing to the folder where you have the above .dll extensions
- Restart your apache server

Comment: it give that: call to undefined function mysql_connect...how can i fix it?

Comment: @kinana.yasin added some details to the answer

Comment: what do you by:Check that "extension_dir" setting is correct, and is pointing to the folder where you have the above .dll extensions!!!i just enable mysql.so

Comment: there is a setting "extension_dir" in the same file, which should point to the folder where you have mysql.so file located.

Comment: i search about mysql.so i can find it...i use php5 by the way!!!where it use to be found?

Comment: typically you have a folder "ext" under your PHP install location.

Answer (score -1):

This is Template file for your project **connect.php**. You can use it.

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//echo 'Connected successfully';
  mysql_select_db('procost') or die('Could not select database');
?>
```